# postgresql + dblink + insert with returning

Tags: postgresql, insert, dblink

I need to insert a record in remote database and get the id inserted. What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE

ticketvar mytable%rowtype;

SqlCommand TEXT;

BEGIN    

ticketvar.c1 := somevalue;
ticketvar.c2 := somevalue;

SqlCommand := 'INSERT INTO mytable ( c1, c2)  VALUES (||ticketvar.c1||, ||ticketvar.c2||) returning tid';

tid =  (select *  from dblink('mydatawrapper',SqlCommand)  AS t1(bigint tid)  );
```

...

It raises an error

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ticketvar"

With select statement, everything works just fine:

```
result = (select *  from dblink('mydatawrapper','SELECT tid FROM mytable WHERE c1='||c1||'')  AS t1(bigint tid) );
```

Comment: Did you try 'INSERT INTO mytable ( c1, c2)  VALUES ('||ticketvar.c1||',' ||'ticketvar.c2||') returning tid' of course this is if c1 and c2 are integers. If they are strings you should add '' in appropriate places. For example ''',''' in place of ',' and '' where you brake string.

Comment: yes and it actually worked! , forgot to close the question. thank you anyway for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Example which worked for me with foreign data wrapper + dblink:

```
-- if text field has apostrophes:
value2 = replace(value2,'''','''''');

q1 = 'INSERT INTO foreign_table1( field1,field2,field3) 
      VALUES ('||value1||','''||value2||''', now()) RETURNING id';

SELECT * FROM dblink('foreign_server', q1) 
         AS foreign_rec(id INTEGER) INTO foreign_table1_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html

You need connection, based on that you can execute your insert with `returning` as with you `sqlCommand`.

To answer the question. To me it looks like you are using plSQL - simple SQL is enough.

Comment: Connection is established through foreign data wrapper "mydatawrapper"

Comment: Yes... I've started answering w/o formatting perhaps that is why I missed that - a bit. Sometime ago I had to do dblink, and that page helped me, so I've answered. :)